# Есть ли будущее у АctionScript 3 для GameDev ?

Tags: actionscript-3

Привет коллеги ! Говорят что Flash + AS3 умирающая ветвь под web, но в игрострое же используется ? Или даже там перешли на HTML5 и большинство разработчиков бросают заниматся такой классной штукой как actionscript ? Вопрос чисто ради интереса ...

Comment: С 2005 года слышу про умирающий флэш, все никак не умрёт.

В этом месяце AS3 вошел в 20-ку самых популярных языков, по индексу TIOBE - http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html.

Comment: Такое чувство что AS3 не умирает, а только начинает жить ...

Answer (score 2):

Это утверждение начало появляться после [небезызвестного письма Стива Джобса](http://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/) о замене флеш-технологии новой встроенной технологией HTML5. В статье описывалось, почему флеш больше не нужен и что взамен предлагает вместо этого HTML5. Пересказ на русский можно почитать [тут](http://alexmak.net/blog/2010/04/29/sj-thoughts-on-flash/). Преимущественно, речь шла о мобильных платформах, ведь пользователи IPhone не имеют возможности использовать Flash Player и смотреть видео. Благодаря HTML5 видео, баннеры и прочая мелочь успешно внедрилась в мобильные платформы и потеснила флеш.

А что насчет более серьезных вещей и RIA приложений?

1. На данный момент [Canvas API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/) имеет всего около 20-ти самых низкуровневых функций и ни одной нормальной библиотеки, которая покрывала хотя бы часть функционала флеш. О том, как удобно и быстро на этом программировать и сколько сил надо затратить я лучше промолчу(тут нужно самому попробовать). Бенчмарки выдали одинаковые показатели, поэтому в производительности выигрыша тоже не получилось.
2. Обе технологии поддерживают теперь GPU, поэтому тут преимущества у WebGL тоже нет.
3. Adobe Flash все таки сделала ход конем для пользователей мобильных устройств и теперь можно конвертировать их приложения в [JavaScript Canvas](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash/how-to/creating-publishing-html5-canvas-document.html) среду.
4. Цены на среду разработки Adobe Flash теперь стали человеческими и доступными.

О какой смерти тут говорить я не представляю, скорее наоборот, HTML5 еле плавает. Хотя может лет через десять он и умрет.

**Обновление**

На будущее загадывать никто не берется, но ближайшие несколько лет он проживет. По крайней мере HTML5 не очень торопится его обгонять и существует проблема кроссбраузерности, стандартизации и создания пригодного инструментария. По крайней мере я бы не расстраивался по поводу его перспектив:

1. флеш предоставляет кучу учебной литературы по принципам именно геймдева
2. этот язык имеет один стандарт c JavaScript - ECMAScript, пэтому перейти с одного на другой будет не сложно
3. геймдевелопер только на одном языке не заканчивает, помимо него учится еще пару(один серверный) и HTML, XML и etc.

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ ! Надеюсь AS3 будет жить и процветать !!! А на перспективу это хороший инструмент для ГеймДева ?

Comment: @СуперСникерс, ИМХО - нет. Лично я уже 2 с половиной года не имею flash player'a и не особо расстроен по этому поводу. PS: flash не нужен

Comment: Обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю что он НУЖЕН, но его следует переработать в более достойный вид без тех багов, которые в нём есть. Но мне кажется разработчики будто сами НЕ хотят что либо делать для достижения качества. Словно продали десяток лет назад компанию наперёд, и сейчас просто доживают срок выпуская обновления банальные.